# How do I do so one value in List can't be changed? (Dart)

Tags: dart

something like this

```
void main() {
  List list = [0, 0, 0];

  final list[1] = 1;
}
```

i want so something like

```
for(i in list) {
list[i] = 2;
}
```

changes every value but the second one in list

here's my code for anyone ho's interested why do I need this
https://github.com/Alexxxiy69/memo2/blob/main/lib/main.dart

Comment: No you cannot do this

Comment: You would need to extend the `List` class and override all methods that mutate the `List` to make them throw runtime errors if something tries to mutate the `List` in a way that affects the element you want to preserve.  Or, since you want to preserve only a single element, you could simply not store it in the `List`. (Why do you want to do this?)

Comment: @jamesdlin could you explain this with code please?

Comment: @jamesdlin also i added link to my program to explain why i want to do this

Comment: Your code has no comments or documentation.  I have no idea what it *intends* to do.  Can you describe in words why you want to do this?

Comment: @jamesdlin simply, it's a game "MEMO". there are a random generated cards, and when you pick two of the same, they stay opened, and you need to open every card. 
i don't know how to do so they stay opened

Comment: Okay, but that still doesn't explain why you need to have a single unmodifiable element for that; such a game should be easily implementable without doing what you're asking for.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to do but the typical way you'd do that is to create a `Card` class and have a `List<Card>`.  Each `Card` then would keep track of whether it's, say, shown or not, and the whatever code is iterating over the `List` would be responsible for skipping over already-shown `Card`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to enforce such a thing at compile-time.

If you *really* want, you could create your own class that provides the `List` interface but that overrides all mutating methods to throw runtime errors if the caller attempts to mutate the `List` in a way that affects the element you want to preserve.  That would be similar to what the [`UnmodifiableListView`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/UnmodifiableListView-class.html) class does:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class PartiallyUnmodifiableList<E> with ListMixin<E> {
  final _internalList = <E>[];
  int? preservedIndex;

  PartiallyUnmodifiableList();

  PartiallyUnmodifiableList.of(List<E> list) {
    _internalList.addAll(list);
  }

  @override
  int get length => _internalList.length;

  @override
  set length(int newLength) => _internalList.length = newLength;

  @override
  void add(E element) => _internalList.add(element);

  @override 
  E operator [](int index) => _internalList[index];

  @override
  void operator []=(int index, E value) {
    if (index == preservedIndex) {
      throw UnsupportedError('Cannot mutate element at $index');
    }

    _internalList[index] = value;
  }
}

void main() {
  var list = PartiallyUnmodifiableList.of([1, 2, 3]);
  list.preservedIndex = 1;
  list[1] = 4; // Throws.
}
```

It would be a significant of work and probably would be tricky.  You also would need to define exactly what it means for one element to be unmodifiable: what if elements are inserted or removed from the `List`?  Should the unmodifiable element always be fixed at a specific index?  Should the element move but whatever element takes its place become unmodifiable?  Should the element move and stay unmodifiable?  What happens when you call `clear()` on your `List`?  Your question is highly under-specified.

The code above shows how you *could* do it, but that doesn't mean that you *should*.  I would consider such a `List` to be very unfriendly and hard-to-use.

Alternatively, since you're trying to preserve only a single value, you perhaps could simply not put that in your `List` and treat it specially.